# Can I assign default props from other component's default props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have two components, both the components are sharing the same props.

Can I assign the default props and propTypes by directly setting it them to other components default props

e.g.

`static propTypes = CookiePreferenceButton.propTypes;`

`static defaultProps = CookiePreferenceButton.defaultProps;`

Where `CookiePreferenceButton` is a stateless component.

```
const CookiePreferenceButton = ({buttonText, buttonStyle, className}) => (
  <button className={styles[className]} style={buttonStyle}>
    {buttonText}
  </button>
);

CookiePreferenceButton.propTypes = {
  buttonText: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  buttonStyle: PropTypes.shape({
    background: PropTypes.string,
    borderColor: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};

CookiePreferenceButton.defaultProps = {
  buttonText: 'Manage Cookie Preference',
  className: 'cookie-preference-preview-button',
  buttonStyle: {
    background: '#209ce9',
    borderColor: '#209ce9',
    color: '#fff',
  },
};

export default CookiePreferenceButton;
```

Comment: Just maintain the common props in a separate file and then import them in both the components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can share default props among components.

For example:

**shapes.js**

```
export const CookiePreferenceButton = PropTypes.shape({
  ...
});
```

**Foo.jsx**

```
import { CookiePreferenceButton } from './shapes';

...

Foo.propTypes = {
  cookies: CookiePreferenceButton,
}
```

**Bar.jsx**

```
import { CookiePreferenceButton } from './shapes';

...

Bar.propTypes = {
  cookies: CookiePreferenceButton,
}
```

Comment: I use this pattern in a few places. You get something similar by default if you use TypeScript.

Comment: It's a functional component from where I want to import default props. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using prop types from other component define a prop types in a separate file and use them in both of the component:

```
export const CookieButton = {
  // ... your prop types
}

// import CookieButton and use it
static defaultProps = CookieButton
// another component
static propTypes = CookieButton;
```